# Collapse with dynamic accordions

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      {{#each forms}}
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=".collapse">
            {{fid}}</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          {{> form}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>

<template name="form">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">First name : {{fname}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Last name : {{lname}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Analysis : {{ydata}}</li>

</template>
```

I am using bootstrap with meteor. I have created a form which adds accordions dynamically according to the form data. The accordions are added successfully. The only problem is it only collapses the first accordion even if I click the second or third one. How can I make the specific accordion collapse when it being added dynamically?

Comment: Can you me working demo in plnkr or codepen?

Answer (score 2):

It's a referencing issue you are having. Looking at your code, this line

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=".collapse">
```

will be repeated for each of the three accordions dynamically generated.

Meaning your `href=".collapse"` attribute in the `a` tag for each accordion will always be pointing to the same `<div class="panel-collapse collapse">` element. That explains why only the first  accordion (first of its type) opens even when you click the second or third accordion triggers.

To get it all working: 
Use a dynamically generated ID referencing on your `href` attribute instead of a class. In other words, use an increment counter or something along those lines. And also make sure you generate a matching ID on your collapse `div` element. As an example, you could have something like:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="{{#dynamicallyGeneratedID}}"> 
  ...
```

then you could have something like:

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="{{dynamicallyGeneratedID}}"> 
  ...
```

So let's say for accordion one that will result in something like:

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#formOne"> 
   ...
```

then your panel body will also be:

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="formOne">
  ...
```

All the best of luck!